# With a foreign key, can I reference a fixed value in a composite primary key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a database structure which includes the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.PaymentProvidersForEntities
(
    PaymentProviderId SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    EntityId BIGINT NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT PK_PaymentProvidersForEntities 
        PRIMARY KEY (PaymentProviderId, EntityId), 
    CONSTRAINT FK_PaymentProvidersForEntities_PaymentProviders 
        FOREIGN KEY (PaymentProviderId) 
        REFERENCES PaymentProviders(PaymentProviderId) 
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT FK_PaymentProvidersForEntities_Entities 
        FOREIGN KEY (EntityId) 
        REFERENCES Entities(EntityId) 
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

Obviously this is a simple many-to-many linking table with a composite primary key. I want another table which references that table but provides data for only one PaymentProvider (i.e. where PaymentProviderId = a fixed value). Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.SpecificPaymentProviderExtraDetails
(
    EntityId BIGINT NOT NULL,
    ExtraDetails NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_PaymentProviderExtraDetails 
        PRIMARY KEY (EntityId), 
    CONSTRAINT FK_PaymentProviderExtraDetails_PaymentProvidersForEntities 
        FOREIGN KEY (EntityId, 1) 
        REFERENCES PaymentProvidersForEntities(EntityId, PaymentProviderId) 
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

Obviously I could just add a nullable 'ExtraDetails' field in the PaymentProvidersForEntities table but I don't find that very elegant as there will be several different types of payment providers, each requiring different types of extra details. Is there an elegant way of doing what I want? If not, then what would be  a better way of achieving the same thing?

Comment: Cascade Deletes and Updates can pose problems for seasoned DBA's. I would recommend you remove them and manualy do the update/deletes that need to cascade

Comment: Can you provide references? I would describe myself as a 'seasoned' DBA and I don't have any problems with them at the moment... but I would be interested to find out what problems they cause others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to store the payment provider ID, and use a CHECK() constraint to make sure it's the one you want. Let's assume you want the payment provider ID to always equal 13.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.PaymentProviderExtraDetails
(
    PaymentProviderID SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 13 CHECK(PaymentProviderID = 13),
    EntityId BIGINT NOT NULL,
    ExtraDetails NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_PaymentProviderExtraDetails 
        PRIMARY KEY (PaymentProviderID, EntityId), 
    CONSTRAINT FK_PaymentProviderExtraDetails_PaymentProvidersForEntities 
        FOREIGN KEY (PaymentProviderID, EntityID) 
        REFERENCES PaymentProvidersForEntities(PaymentProviderId, EntityId) 
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

I prefer this approach to a persisted column, because this approach follows the [principle of least surprise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).  It's also much simpler to extend to support two, three, or four payment providers instead of one.

If I were you, I'd reconsider the table name. It *probably* ought to be named after the single payment provider that you're recording data for.

Comment: This looks like an even better solution. Thanks! Yes, the idea would have been to have tables with different names - like PayPalExtraDetails or GoogleCheckoutExtraDetails. I've updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: Also, it's still not as elegant as if you could just use the syntax I suggested in the question. I wonder if an even better solution will come along?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a persisted computed column to the referencing column list:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.p(i1 INT, i2 INT, CONSTRAINT p_pk PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (i1,i2));
CREATE TABLE dbo.c(id INT PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,i1 INT, i2 AS 1 PERSISTED, CONSTRAINT c_fk FOREIGN KEY (i1,i2) REFERENCES dbo.p(i1,i2));
INSERT INTO dbo.p(i1,i2)VALUES(42,1);
INSERT INTO dbo.c(id,i1)VALUES(111,42);
```

Comment: is this standard sql? or is it specific to some database ?

Comment: This was tested on Microsoft SQL Server. It is probably not standard.

Answer (score -1):

If your second table's primary Key is a surrogate key and you make a foreign key to the part of the composite key you want that will do it for you.

For example, pseudosql

Foo 
bar int primarykey
foobar int primarykey

test
testFoo int primarykey
foobar int foriengkey

Just make sure you put only the items in test that you want. If you really want to be safe you can put a constraint on `foobar` making sure it only has values you want

Comment: I don't know if this works, but I may be misunderstanding. Can you clarify what you mean? Maybe with real SQL?

Comment: *"If your second table's primary Key is a surrogate key and you make a foreign key to the part of the composite key you want that will do it for you."* First, that won't work in any SQL dbms that complies with SQL standards. The target of a foreign key reference has to have either a primary key constraint or a unique constraint on its column(s). Second, even if it worked, it wouldn't solve the OP's problem. The "second" table needs to refer to one and only one payment provider ID.